# Update app in the marketplace wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, submit, marketplace

I have been trying for 3 hours to update a new .xap for my current app.

Can you please give me some intructions:

I have read a lot of posts and I didn't find anything:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh546830(v=vs.92).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg442301(v=vs.92).aspx

I always get this error message:

> This application name is already in use or one of your other apps

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Apphub where your apps are find the one you wanna update then you click the app and on the apps page on the Lifecycle tab there is a link "Submit an Update" it has a + sign before it too. So if you click it then you get the page for submitting an update which looks exactly like the submit new app page.

Then you choose your update *.xap and upload it with a greater version number then the last one and you can write to your details change pricing if you want and you are ready with the update.

I hope this helps you, tried to explain it the best i could.

Comment: Ok, I have found the option Submit and Updated...I don't know why yesterday the app hub doesn't show me this option. Anyway, I want to comment some of the main steps: I changed the number of the version in WMAppManifest.xml and also (I don't if it is really needed) the number of the version in AssemblyInfo file of the project. And anything more: Submit And Update option, same name but different number of version.

Comment: @JuanPedro you can change but i think they only take a look at the WMAppManifest.xml, and the new version number you set in the submit form. The File name can be different from the original File name.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, BigL....The process to certificate the app, the first time or post updates, is annoying...spend too much time!!!

Comment: @JuanPedro you are welcome, sadly you can't change the time it takes to certify your apps, for me it takes 3-4 days, so be patient. :)

Comment: Facing the same issue. Could you please provide me some articles/steps for uploading update for the windows phone app?